# Retrieve records from oracle table with batch inputs where some column criteria can be optional

Tags: sql, oracle

I figured out that we can retrieve records from an `Oracle` table with batch inputs as follows:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    invoices
WHERE
    (invoice_id, entity_id) IN 
                               (
                                   (1, 101), 
                                   (2, 102), 
                                   (3, 102)
                               )
```

Now, I need to fire a query where the input for one of the columns is immaterial, but still be able to do batch querying.

E.g.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    invoices
WHERE
    (invoice_id, entity_id, vendor_id) IN 
                               (
                                   (1, 101, 201), 
                                   (2, 102, 202), 
                                   -- no criteria on vendor_id for the tuple below
                                   (3, 102)   
                               )
```

If I run this query, the query engine reports the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Is it possible to do such a query in the first place? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle: Expression Lists:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions014.htm#i1033664)

> The number of expressions in each set must match the number of
>   expressions before the operator in the comparison condition or before
>   the IN keyword in the membership condition.

You can separate these conditions:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    invoices
WHERE
    (invoice_id, entity_id, vendor_id) IN 
                               (
                                   (1, 101, 201), 
                                   (2, 102, 202)
                               )
    or 
    (invoice_id, entity_id) IN 
                               (
                                   -- no criteria on vendor_id for the tuple below
                                   (3, 102)   
                               )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    invoices
WHERE
    (invoice_id, entity_id, vendor_id) IN 
                               (
                                   select 1, 101, 201 from dual
                                   union 
                                   select 2, 102, 202 from dual
                                   union
                                   select 3, 102, vendor_id from invoices
                               )
```